# Why does scikit-image return NaN for the color difference of this color with itself?

Tags: floating-point, scikit-image

I have the following snippet:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import color

c = np.array([0., 1.59607713, 0.87755709])
print(color.deltaE_cmc(c, c))
```

I expected this code to print 0 or a number close to 0, but it prints `nan` instead. Why? To my knowledge `c` is a valid color in the L*a*b* color space.

Comment: One guess is division of a difference function by the lightness. That could result in 0/0, one of the NaN expressions.

Comment: Please post a bug report on the scikit-image GitHub repo, then we can fix this.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt [Done.](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/1908)